# Testing api response gives me error because replacement character � with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, html-entities

I am facing a problem testing with protractor.

I am comparing text in my web app with an API I make requests. 
When I GET a response with Postman, text is written with HTML entities as: `&uacute(ú) &ntilde(ñ)` and I handle it with a `decodeHTMLEntities()` function to decode those entities. 
All is fine up to that point.

The problem comes when I get a `ñ` or a `¿` (not encoded). I call the API in my test and those characters are return as `�` so the test fails. 
For example:

```
ApiObject = {Country: 'España'}
expect('España').toBe(ApiObject.Country)
```

gives: `Expected 'España' to be 'Espa�a'`

It is not a file format error because if I do `console.log('España')`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't assert be used for this. Which comes by default in node.js

**Positive**

```
var assert = require('assert')
ApiObject = {
    Country: 'España'
}
assert.equal(ApiObject.Country, 'España')
```

**Negative**

```
var assert = require('assert')
ApiObject = {
    Country: 'EspañA'
}
assert.equal(ApiObject.Country, 'España')
```

changed the country value at last a capital 'A'

[image]